# Webmatrix SSL certificate: 'unable to get local issuer certificate'

Tags: ssl-certificate, iis-7.5

I'm working on a project that interacts with Twitter's API using PHP-cURL to built my RESTful requests. Something like (take my word for it that all variables are assigned, etc):

```
$headers = array( 
    "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1", 
    "Host: api.twitter.com", 
    "User-Agent: Twitter Application-only OAuth App v.1",
    "Authorization: Basic ".$base64_encoded_bearer_token."",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", 
    "Content-Length: 29"
    ); 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials"); 

    $header = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $retrievedhtml = curl_exec($ch);

    echo curl_error($ch); //Throws Error

    curl_close($ch);
```

I know the code is good, because I've uploaded it to one of my Pagodabox Apps and it works perfectly. However, when I'm testing locally, using Webmatrix, cURL throws the error `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`. So I know it's on my end.

That wouldn't be so bad if I knew I were uploading the file to Pagodabox, but the production server that this app will be on is running Windows server (which is why I'm running Webmatrix for my local testing) and my preliminary tests are having the same problems.

**Update**: 
For those running into the same problem, I found it helpful to read through these projects' code:

[Codebird-PHP](https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-php)
[Twitter-Application-Only-Authentication-OAuth-PHP](https://github.com/jonhurlock/Twitter-Application-Only-Authentication-OAuth-PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURL will look for trusted SSL certificates in a file called `curl-ca-bundle.crt`, in the following paths on Windows:

- The directory your program is in
- The current working directory
- `%windir%\system32`
- `%windir%`
- The directories in `%PATH%`

If it doesn't find this, or the first one it finds doesn't contain the issuer certificate for your certificate (you have to trust your own certificate), this error will be thrown.

One possible way around this is to include the rest of the certificate chain in the certificate you are presenting (for PEM certificates, simply concatenate the certificate, the certificate that signed your certificate, and the certificate that signed that one, until you get to a root certificate, which usually means the file contains 3 certificates).

Comment: This worked beautifully (once I figured out how to do it).

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed you last week - glad to see you got it working.